# Aurelia - bound control's backing property setter called twice

Tags: aurelia

I implemented a custom control which is basically a styled file uploader specifically for images, which allows the preview of images. The problem is that I experience a weird behavior: the setter of the property to which the regular HTML `<input type="file">` is bound gets called twice in FF 53, IE 11, Edge 38, but not in Chrome 57. I have no idea why this happens, perhaps some of you have experienced similar behavior and know a solution.

The markup is the following:

```
<template>

  <!-- markup for preview functionality, irrelevant here -->

  <input type="file" class="sr-only" id="${id}" aria-describedby="${id}-help" multiple accept="image/*" files.bind="imageGroup" />

  <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm" aria-hidden="true" for="${id}" role="button">
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add files
  </label>

</template>
```

The backing TypeScript code:

```
import { bindable, bindingMode, autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { DialogService } from 'aurelia-dialog';
import { Confirm } from '../confirm';

@autoinject
export class ImageUploader {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) imageArray: Array<File> = null;
  @bindable id: string = null;
  @bindable maxImageCount: number = 10;
  @bindable maxFileSizeKiloBytes: number = 2048;

  constructor(private dialogService: DialogService) { }

  idChanged(newValue: string) {

    if (!newValue) {
      throw Error('The id parameter needs a value in order to make the file uploader work.');
    }

  }

  set imageGroup(fileList: FileList) {
    console.log('imageGroup');
    if (!fileList || !fileList.length) return;
    if (!this.imageArray) return;

    for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; ++i) {
      let file = fileList.item(i);

      if (this.imageArray.length >= this.maxImageCount) {
        // TODO: Alert: maximum number of images reached
      } else {
        if (file && file.type.startsWith('image/')) {
          // Size is in bytes. Div by 1024 to get kilobytes.
          if (file.size / (1024) > this.maxFileSizeKiloBytes) {
            // TODO: Alert: Image file too large.
          } else {
            this.imageArray.push(file);
          }
        } else {
          // TODO: Alert: unsupported media type.
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I use the "hide the default file uploader and style a bound label instead" trick to style the uploader itself - I only say this to point out that I've checked if maybe this is the cause, but it's not, the same behavior can be experienced if I show the default file uploader and use that.

You can also see that I've bound the `<input type="file">` to a setter-only property. I've done that because this property is basically just a proxy which populates another array (which is not in the control, this is what is bound to the control) which is necessary because I need to allow the user to upload files in multiple turns so that (s)he can select files from different folders.

The rest of the code is irrelevant, because the `console.log` line runs twice whenever I select some files, so the error is located somewhere here - I am just unable to figure out exactly what is causing this to happen.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed that using [setter](https://gist.run/?id=bb69c8bf87d4860976c391dc65bc5d33) on that case causes to call your setter two times in FF, aurelia created another setter for every property that needs to observe. However you can achieve same behavior using [observable](https://gist.run/?id=11f8af9e1d33917ef34141374acd80c6) with minimal changes and also provided encapsulation in this case. See those gist.run link. More info [here](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/06/working-aurelia-observable/).

**UPDATE**

For Firefox this is still open as a [bug](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/314). But a workaround using `change.delegate` as elefantino and abemeister said works on FF, see gist [here](https://gist.run/?id=fa022c4210079c4f8e7a5fbddb32efed).

Comment: That solution works in IE & Chrome, however in FF, there is some really weird behavior. The observer method gets called for the first time, but try selecting another file again and it won't be called.

Comment: It seems that it was a [bug](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/314). Please see update for workaround.

Comment: Thanks for that information, it seems to be working with that workaround.